# Prevent Horizontal Scrollbar from Appearing in Overflowing Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to prevent the scroll bar from appearing when the div `.boxB` overflows and I am unsure why my code is not working. In other words,  I am trying to remove the horizontal scroll bar only when the browser width is less then the width of boxB. This way, the scroll bar will only appear when the browser width is less then `.boxA`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU5ET.jpg

The light blue represents the screen. The yellow is a background div, and the aqua is the foreground div where its width exceeds the screen width. In this case, I do not want the scroll bar to appear. I have used `overflow-x:hidden` but that did not do the trick.

HTML:

```
<div class="boxA">boxA  
  <div class="boxB">boxB</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxA {
    background: yellow;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}

.boxB {
    background: aqua;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Your goal is to just prevent the scrollbar from appearing?

The code you've provided does exactly that: http://jsfiddle.net/dy8g5/

What browser are you still seeing the scrollbar on?

Comment: My goal is to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing for .boxB. I am using Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: Well.. there is NO scroll bar for .boxB. But there is a scroll bar on document body because boxB is too wide.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe I should re-word my question. I am trying to remove the horizontal scroll bar only when the browser width is less then the width of boxB.

Answer (score 3):

May be, `overflow-x: hidden;` must be uses for .boxA?

Comment: I tried applying that to `.boxA` but that just shrank the width of `.boxB` to `.boxA`'s width.

Comment: Then apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to body. That shrank width of .boxB to body's width. I think, this is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in my post (I have corrected this). I am trying to remove the horizontal scroll bar only when the browser width is less then the width of boxB.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write

```
overflow: hidden
```

Comment: I tried applying that to `.boxB` but that did not work. I don't want to apply it to `body` because I still want the user to scroll horizontally if the browser becomes smaller then `.boxA`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.boxA {
    background: yellow;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.boxB {
    background: aqua;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;

}
```

`overflow` must be on a tag which wraps too large content (in your case - `boxA` wraps `boxB`). So, if you do not want something to go outside wrapper - you must put `overflow` on wrapper

Comment: When I applied `overflow-x:hidden` to .boxA, .boxB's width shrank to 800px. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: try to add this class `body{overflow-x: hidden;}` and remove `overflow-x: hidden;` from `boxA` class

Comment: That sort of works, but I only want to remove the horizontal scroll bar only when the browser width is less then the width of boxB.

Comment: But there will be no scroll bar if browser width is more than width of boxB. So what is the problem? if browser window is large than boxB - no scroll bars. Just it became smaller - scroll bar will not appear because of overflow-x:hidden on body

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I want the scroll bar to appear only when the browser width is less then .boxA.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, boxeA is the parent and Box B is the child.

CSS property **overflow** used like this :

```
.boxeA
 {
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

will prevent a part of the boxeB (which is the child of boxeA) to be displayed when it is more bigger than it's own parent.

boxeA is like a mask on boxeB.

in the url you have given, to prevent the aqua boxe to be entirly displayed, you have to put the aqua boxe as a child of the light blue one,
and give the light blue box a css property like this :

```
.light_blue
 {
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you want, here is a possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/dy8g5/3/

Parameters:

1. .boxB must be visible outside of .boxA, with no horizontal scrollbar.
2. The browser should not have a horizontal scrollbar, if the browser width is smaller than the width of .boxB

The solution was to use a media query to hide the horizontal scrollbar, IF the browser width is smaller than the width of .boxB

```
@media all and (max-width: 1001px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 801px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }
}

.boxA {
    background: yellow;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}

.boxB {
    background: aqua;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: There is also one more requirement. The horizontal scrollbar needs to appear if the browser width is less then .boxA. I am currently using Bootstrap and so I'm not sure if its a good idea to use `@media` tag as it might get confused with Bootstrap's `@media`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to accommodate your last requirement.  `@media` should not conflict with your bootstrap's.  You can have multiple `@media` definitions and they won't conflict (unless perhaps they target the same elements with the same css attributes).  Here is the jsFiddle with the updated coded: http://jsfiddle.net/dy8g5/4/