# How to Prevent Div from Scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website where I have .wrapper that runs vertical along the middle of the page, and .banner that spreads horizontal near the top of the page. The .banner will contain a 1600x400 image along with some links. What I am trying to do is create an effect where the banner will 'run off' the page. To do this, I want the horizontal scroll bar to only appear when the browser width is less then .wrapper width. I am trying to achieve the effect of something like the [EA Homepage](http://www.ea.com/ca) where the horizontal scrollbars only appear when the browser width is less then the content and not the banner.

Image of what I want:

> [image]

Requirements:

- horizontal bar to be displayed only when browser width is less then
  .wrapper's width
- horizontal bar to NOT be displayed when browser width is less then .banner's width
- .banner must be visible all the way to the right side of the browser (cannot be cut off by .wrapper)

I saw this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432688/prevent-horizontal-scrollbar-from-appearing-in-overflowing-div) that is similar to mine but it was not solved. I tried a few of the suggested solutions but it did not help me.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/NZb3w/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1600x400">
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccffff;
    height: 800px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try

```
.wrapper {
  min-width: 960px; 
  overflow-x:auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will allow the width to of the `.wrapper` to stretch greater than 960px, but once it hits 959px, it'll add the scrollbar.

Comment: I need .wrapper to stop at 960px though. I tried your code but .wrapper stretched 100%.

Comment: If you need it set always to 960px, try just `width: 960px` with the `overflow: auto;`  If you'd prefer it to shrink with smaller viewports, try `max-width: 960px; width: 100%;`. In either case, keep the `overflow: auto;`. That's what makes the scrollbar appear when the viewport is smaller than the width of your `.banner`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use max-width so when the div will get the max width avable it will set scroll-x: or y whatever you need.

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccffff;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I modified my question to include an example. My example is http://www.ea.com/ca where the horizontal scroll bar only appears when the browser width is less then the content and not the banner.

Answer (score -1):

use css 'min-width' property to your page or width, so that the element won't shrink after the limit and scrollbars will appear after this. Use overflow:hidden to disable scrollbars.

Comment: Sorry, where do I attach those tags? I tried using `min-width:960px;` on the body, and `overflow:hidden;` on .wrapper but it did not work.